# How to use interp1 in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the data

```
x=[14.0716101600000 17.7292101600000    21.3868101600000    21.3868101600000    25.0444101600000    28.7020101600000    32.3596101600000    36.0172101600000    39.6748101600000    43.3324101600000    46.9900101600000    50.6476101600000    54.3052101600000    57.9628101600000    61.6204101600000    65.2780101600000    68.9356101600000    72.5932101600000    76.2508101600000    79.9084101600000    83.5660101600000    87.2236101600000]

y=[0    0   0   0.152400000000000   0.152400000000000   0.533400000000000   0.685800000000000   0.838200000000000   0.990600000000000   1.14300000000000    1.14300000000000    1.14300000000000    1.29540000000000    1.44780000000000    1.60020000000000    1.75260000000000    1.90500000000000    2.05740000000000    2.20980000000000    2.36220000000000    2.51460000000000    2.66700000000000]

new_x=[21.38,25.03,28.70,32.33,35.99,39.55,45.13,48.80,54.38,58.05];
```

However, when I use `interp1` like

```
new_y = interp1(x,y,new_x);
```

it doesn't work.Please tell me why.Thank you so much!

Comment: Does it appear an error-message?

Comment: When you say that "it doesn't work" you force people to guess why. In this case, the answer is clear, and given by Mohsen. But far more helpful is to actually give the ENTIRE error message.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` vector must be strictly monotonic. In your data, third and fourth elements of `x` are equal. If you remove, say, fourth element from `x` and `y` by

```
x(4)=[];
y(4)=[];
```

it works without problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It should be monotonic if I change x(4) for a little which is fine.

Comment: @fengdongyuxi glad that it helped. Please choose it as the answer if you find it correct to help the community.